# Disable image magnifier javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and i want to get image source using JavaScript on click. The problem is that the image magnifier places a square box on mouse position and i can't grab image source. Can i disable image magnifier(can be any) using chrome content script so i can grab image source. 
I have already tried these events on image click/hover.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/event-stoppropagation.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/events-preventdefault.htm

These don't have any effect.

Comment: Try setting an `pointer-events:none !important` CSS on that square.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for reply. Will try and let you know when i get back to my desk